# Use filterFilter to filter data

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, filter

I want to filter retrived sharepoint list using filterFilter.But it is giving ***error as:**angular.min.js:89 TypeError: filterFilter is not a function*****
Not able to inject filter to controller since am using $https.
Below is the code,

```
 $scope.update=function() 
    {

    $scope.drop=$scope.states.Id;
     console.log($scope.drop);
 $http({

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('List')/items?$select=State/Title,Title,Id&$expand=State/Title",  
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  

       $scope.city= filterFilter(data.d.results,{State:$scope.drop});
       console.log($scope.city);

    })
   .error (function(data, status, headers, config) {  })
```

}

Comment: Have you injected `$filter` to the controller?

Comment: Yes but still it is giving error

Comment: Please show the code where filterFilter is assigned.

Comment: I'm not able to assign to controller,i tried with $filter as below:var app=angular.module('cascadingDrpdwn',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($filter,$scope,$http)

Comment: Show the whole code, including the constructor

Comment: Now error is not there but it is not giving the filtered data,can anyone tell me how to compare with lookup column in filter

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply ,i got my answer,Complete code is below

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($filter,$scope,$http,filterFilter)
```

{

```
 $http({

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('States')/items",  
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
       $scope.State=data.d.results;
       console.log($scope.State);

    })
   .error (function(data, status, headers, config) {  })
```

$scope.update=function() 
        {

```
    $scope.drop=$scope.states.Id;
     console.log($scope.drop);
 $http({

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('City')/items?$select=State/Title,Title,Id,*&$expand=State",  
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  

       $scope.city=filterFilter(data.d.results,{StateId:$scope.drop});
       console.log($scope.city);

    })
   .error (function(data, status, headers, config) {  })
```

}

});

**If you use * in $select,Lookup field Id can be retrieved,using that you can compare :)**